# Error serializing `.meetups[0].title` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/" `

Tags: mongodb, next.js

I'm using next js with MongoDB, I'm getting the error serializing when submitting the form

error
Server Error
Error: Error serializing `.meetups[0].title` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/".
Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.

```
function HomePage(props){
    return <MeetupList meetup={props.meetups} ></MeetupList>
}


export async function getStaticProps(){

    const client =  await MongoClient.connect("mongodb+srv://User:Password@cluster0.random.mongodb.net/meetups?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
   
   const db = client.db();
   
   const meetupsCollection =  db.collection("meetups");

   const meetups = await meetupsCollection.find().toArray();

   

   client.close();
   

    return {
      props: {
          meetups : meetups.map(meetup =>( {
              title: meetup.title , 
              address: meetup.address , 
              source: meetup.source ,
              id : meetup._id.toString()
              

          }))
      },
      revalidate: 1
    };
}

export default HomePage;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should wrap the `meetups` prop value with `JSON.stringify`, see below:

```
return {
        props: {
          meetups: JSON.parse(
            JSON.stringify(
              meetups.map((meetup) => ({
                title: meetup.title,
                address: meetup.address,
                source: meetup.source,
                id: meetup._id.toString(),
              }))
            )
          ),
        },
        revalidate: 1,
      };
```